# Mod_rewrite not redirecting all cases correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I always seem to have trouble with this and no matter what I try I can't get all cases to redirect correctly.

I currently have

```
example.com/anything
```

correctly redirects to

```
example.com/track.php?memb=anything
```

and basically any url with a filetype at the end should ignore all redirects. I also have a subdomain rule at the top which I think is implemented correctly to not interfere with what I am trying to add. All of this is currently working correctly with the following code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)?  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?           [NC]

RewriteRule .*           track.php?memb=%1        [L,E=END]
```

---

I need to add the following rule:

```
example.com/c/whatever
```

needs to redirect to

```
example.com/page2.php?c=whatever
```

After many attempts and modifications of some of the current rules, I can't seem to get it working but I think  I'm close with

```
RewriteRule ^c/(.*)$ page2.php?c=$1 [L,E=END]
```

Comment: Looks fine, but where did you put it in relation to the already present rewrite conditions / other rules?

Comment: When I put it right above the last rule, it still redirects to track.php and also suddenly doesn't load any of my css files which are located in .com/css/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` is only valid for the next `RewriteRule`. Also,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)?  [NC]
```

will match anything with a `.` in the name. Since you have a `?` at the end, it won't matter if the extension has a valid name or not.

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$   [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/?        page2.php?c=$1           [L,E=END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      !\.(jpg|png|css|js|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?          track.php?memb=$1        [L,E=END]
```

Comment: ok I removed the first / in both rules and they are both redirecting properly, but the c/test page doesn't load any css (I assume because the css is in the .com/css/ folder, which starts with "c") So RewriteRule ^c/([^/]+)/? works, but any idea on how to exempt the 'css' folder?

Comment: Turns out the css problem was my fault, href="css/main.css" wasn't being found but changing it to href="/css/main.css" works for all cases. Feel free to remove the css rule from your answer. Thanks for the help.